# How are we doing? Are we going down?

Tags: discussion

I see that most of the questions have a very low number of views. Hardly any above 200. Are we going down? How are we doing? Can you guys help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Stats currently suggest we had a bit of a slump through the winter, but are back on the increase now, and we are doing a lot better than this time last year in most ways.

Our average page views have doubled twice in the last 2 years as well.

We are still small, definitely, and it would be nice if we could grow faster, but we are doing okay.

Answer (score 2):

Not all questions have low views, this question:

[What is this tool on a Swiss Army knife for?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/what-is-this-tool-on-a-swiss-army-knife-for)

### Received nearly 9000 views in 8 days!

Answer (score 2):

Subjectively I feel the last couple of days/weeks we are attracting so many new people to the page and a lot of questions with many answers (also from lots of new people involved). I like it a lot. Also a bunch of traffic for the *new* fishing topic.

Therefore I got curious and checked the Q/day ratio yesterday. It increased over the last months but it is still low at approx 3. But in my opinion the key are people. Attracting a diverse crowd is great for the page!

(Unfortunately I myself am not so active at the moment, sorry but I am missing time^^)